# How can I check to see if a Python script was started interactively?

Tags: python, interactive

I'd like for a script of mine to have 2 behaviours, one when started as a scheduled task, and another if started manually. How could I test for interactiveness?

EDIT: this could either be a cron job, or started by a windows batch file, through the scheduled tasks.

Comment: "Scheduled task"?  Started by what piece of software?  What platform?  "Manually?"  From IDLE?  From the Command-line?  What platform?  What shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for interactive shell in a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108330/checking-for-interactive-shell-in-a-python-script)

Answer (score 11):

You should simply add a command-line switch in the scheduled task, and check for it in your script, modifying the behavior as appropriate.  Explicit is better than implicit.

One benefit to this design: you'll be able to test both behaviors, regardless of how you actually invoked the script.

Comment: Agreed.  Run the script normally with awesomeApp and as a batch job with awesomeApp --batch.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know if you're reading from a terminal (not clear if that is enough of a distinction, please clarify) you can use

```
sys.stdin.isatty()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add a command line switch when you're calling it with cron:

python yourscript.py -scheduled

then in your program

```
import sys

if "-scheduled" in sys.argv:
    #--non-interactive code--
else: 
    #--interactive code--
```

Comment: at least use the conventional "--scheduled"