# How to determine if Terminal supports ANSI with python?

Tags: python, eclipse, console, window

The question is in the title :)

More precisely, I use colorama to have coloured output from my script :

```
from colorama import init, Fore

init() # comment if running from Eclipse
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
```

I mainly use my script with 2 terminal :

- the Eclipse console, more precisely the ANSI console plugin, which supports ANSI control sequences
- the Windows console, which can output colors but not with ANSI control sequences.

Normally, colorama.init() determines if Windows is used and modifies the ANSI sequences so that colors are displayed correctly.

But this behaviour is not needed when executing the script from within Eclipse. In fact, colours won't display because colorama.init() enables ANSI sequences replacement (we're on Windows after all) but Eclipse console doesn't understand the Windows sequences.

How can I detect from my script that I'm running Eclipse or Windows Console ?

Typically, I'd like to do:

```
from colorama import init, Fore

if windows_console():
    init()
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
```

Comment: Please add some code to your question :)

Comment: code added and a little more explanations to what I think is the problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if python script is being run in a terminal or via GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818511/how-to-tell-if-python-script-is-being-run-in-a-terminal-or-via-gui)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but my question was in fact a reformulation of [How to tell if python script is being run in a terminal or via GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818511/how-to-tell-if-python-script-is-being-run-in-a-terminal-or-via-gui?lq=1)

os.isatty(0) seems to work.